# pcl::VoxelGrid<>::filter crash: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I am trying to downsample a `PointXYZRGB` point cloud by using `pcl::VoxelGrid<>::filter` with brewed PCL-1.8 (latest brewed version) on macOS Sierra.

I followed the tutorial here http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/voxel_grid.php, which worked fine. Then I modified the point type into pcl::PointXYZRGB. After the modification my program crashes with the error:

> PointCloud before filtering: 460400 data points (x y z).PointCloud
>   after filtering: 41049 data points (x y
>   z).test_voxel(22372,0x7fff9663e3c0) malloc:
>   *** error for object 0x10d4bc020: pointer being freed was not allocated ***  set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/filters/voxel_grid.h>

typedef pcl::PointXYZRGB PointT;
typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> CloudT;

int
main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    CloudT::Ptr cloud (new CloudT());
    CloudT::Ptr cloud_filtered (new CloudT());

  // Fill in the cloud data
  pcl::PCDReader reader;
  // Replace the path below with the path where you saved your file
  reader.read ("table_scene_lms400.pcd", *cloud); // Remember to download the file first!

  std::cerr << "PointCloud before filtering: " << cloud->width * cloud->height 
       << " data points (" << pcl::getFieldsList (*cloud) << ").";

  // Create the filtering object
  pcl::VoxelGrid<PointT> sor;
  sor.setInputCloud (cloud);
  const float grid_size = 0.01f;
  sor.setLeafSize (grid_size, grid_size, grid_size);
  sor.filter (*cloud_filtered); // <==== culprit

  std::cerr << "PointCloud after filtering: " << cloud_filtered->width * cloud_filtered->height 
       << " data points (" << pcl::getFieldsList (*cloud_filtered) << ").";

  return (0);
}
```

I tried to hack on this but still can’t figure out what could possibly go wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: this seems to be a macOS-specific problem. The same program runs well on Ubuntu 16.04 with PCL-1.7.

Comment: I guess it was an issue with my recently reinstalled OS. Solved by reinstalling PCL and clearing cmake cache (removing `CMakeFiles/` and `CMakeCache.txt`).

Comment: Actually, I was able to reproduce the issue on Windows 10. PCL installation was painful, but eventually done successfully, following https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/4462 . So far (did some simple planar segmentations) no trouble. Up to said VoxelGrid-freeing crash.